# Examples of vectors which are Non-euclidean

Tags: vectors, geometry

I am watching Tensor for beginners by Eigenchris, and I was confused when he said that, not all vectors are Euclidean. So, can someone explain me the meaning behind this by an example or visualisation

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Sure mate, but not advance 

Answer (score 0):

Euclidean vectors are vectors in a Euclidean space.There are other spaces which dont have the properties [Euclid describes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Euclidean_geometry)

A example:the [world line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_line) of any object?

Note:We cannot understand intuitively non-Euclidean spaces because our human logic doesnt let us do it.I think if you are interested in differential geometry ,a introduction to Special and General Relativity  would help to get a bigger picture of what is going on and I strongly recommend Brilliant.To be honest non-Euclidean geometries are used only in Special and General Relativity , maybe in Geography as well.

Comment: Another example of non-Euclidean vectors - the RGB co-ordinates of a colour form a vector in colour space, but this is not a geometric/Euclidean vector.

Comment: Um, isn't spacetime flat in special relativity? I thought that the idea of spacetime curvature didn't enter into the picture until one studied _general_ relativity. Also, you can take the "maybe" out of Geography. The surface of the Earth is _not_ flat. The angles between the sides of a triangle laid out on the surface of the Earth add up to more than 180 degrees.

Comment: @SolomonSlow even flat spacetime is not Euclidean so any world line isnt a Euclidean vector.

Comment: [Wikipedia seems to say](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_manifold), that if a manifold is both "flat," and "[complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space)" then it's a Euclidean space. But I'll agree with you about the world line because a world line is a _path_ and obviously it takes more than just four coordinates to completely specify an arbitrary path through a 4D space.